# MongoDB large array or documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

We are trying to save profile views.

We created a schema something like that

```js
{
  user: userId,
  viewers: []
}
```

We think the viewers array could have millions of items

So would it make more sense to do it this way?

```js
{
  user: userId,
  viewer: viewerId
},
{
  user: userId,
  viewer: viewerId
},
{
  user: userId,
  viewer: viewerId
}
```

In this way this collection could have millions of documents

What is the best way to handling this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be better, it's way more easy to analyze data. And will not cause the limit of 16mb in one document.

```
{
  user: userId,
  viewer: viewerId
},
{
  user: userId,
  viewer: viewerId
},
{
  user: userId,
  viewer: viewerId
}
```